# dismiss view controller before presenting to new view controller

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I have three view controllers: 1,2,3

I moved from `1 --> 2` then from `2 ---> 3` now I want to go from `3 ----> 1` and so on.

I need to dismiss the view comntroller number `2` when I'm on `3`
because if I leave view controller number '2' on I seem to have a memory leak. If I repeat this process many times, it may make app slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - in your view controller button action

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```